# Convert 4 gang to 3 gang switch box

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch

I’ve a block of 4 switches in my house. One switch doesn’t work. Like it doesn’t do anything near as I can tell. How to make this a 3 gang?  There a thing as a 4 plate cover with a blank? May look silly to me.

Ok so my guess is the one switch went to an outlet in the middle of the icing room floor but I never checked it and I’ve removed the outlet a few years ago.

Comment: Is the non-functional switch at one end of the bank of switches, or somewhere in the middle?  Is it a single pole switch (with ON and OFF marked on the switch handle), or a 3 or 4 way switch (no markings on the toggle)?

Comment: With that outlet removed, is every point along the wall still within 6' of a receptacle?  If not, it must go back in...

Comment: The outlet is in the middle of the floor. Like. middle of the floor. And as the house was built in the 1920's I hear what you are saying about code saying outlets need to be every 6' but I kinda doubt it makes a difference at this point. Not to mention all the additional outlets I had installed when I moved in as there was barely one outlet per room.

Comment: Can you provide a picture of the inside of the box so that we can see the switches and wiring?

Answer (score 2):

Unless you are planning to do some patching and painting I am afraid you are stuck with a 4G box. If you want to remove the switch because its just irritating you can use a switch blank shown below:
[image]

These can be found in most big box hardware stores and online. They come in different colors and can be found in decora style also.

Good luck.

Comment: This indeed! I ended up getting the gfci blank. I couldn't find a 3 gfci and 1 blank 4 gang terminal anywhere online for under 20$ in the correct color. Thanks!